# Does make sense use dynamic learning rate in AdamOptimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm dvelopping a convolutional neural network for images recognition based on three own classes.
I built an AlexNet-based model to train.
I'd like to know two things:

1. *AdamOptimizer* performs a learning rate decay internally (from a fixed given value) or not ?
2. In case of not, can I use `tf.train.exponential_decay` to perform decay ?

Small examples are apprecciated.
Thanks

Comment: More than downvote, can I have an answer to understand something new ? Or a person must be omniscient ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in [adam.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L30) `AdamOptimizer` will adjust its learning rate.

The learning rate you pass to the constructor just gives the initial value to start with.

So yes, it does not make much sense to use exponential decay on `AdamOptimizer` but on gradient descent or momentum optimizer. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/6c875697dc9ceb0b83e283577c3961c652a92a07/resnet/resnet_main.py) for an example.

Comment: Really thanks. I was sure it was like that, but I ask this question because I red a lot of things also about Residual Learning `https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf`, and I was little bit in confusion.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. That `AdamOptimizer` takes a `learning_rate` argument also make one unsure.

Answer (score 4):

> AdamOptimizer performs a learning rate decay internally (from a fixed given value) or not ?

Yes, Adam does perform a learning rate decay.

You should have a look at how Adam works:

> D. Kingma and J. Ba, “Adam: A method for stochastic optimization,”
>   arXiv preprint arXiv:1412.6980, Dec. 2014. [Online]. Available:
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980

To sum it up: Adam is RMSProp with momentum and bias correction. A very nice explanation is here: http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#adam